# How to remove white blur edge when scrolled to end?

Tags: android, android-view

I'll try my best to explain this one. In Android, when you scroll something to the end, it displays a white sort of blurry thingy like below as an indication that no more scrolling can be done. This kind of behaviour can be seen in ListViews, ScrollViews etc.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFusM.png]

How do I disable it? It looks ugly.
Feel free to edit this question, I really can't find the right words for this thing.

Comment: Not really sure how to fix, but the feature is called 'overscroll' so you could google around for things to disable overscroll in Android. This might be simply ignored though by different manufacturers like Samsung etc so it could turn out difficult to get this gone for every device

Comment: you can use overscrollmode property of scrollview or ListView

Comment: @AshishJani would you like to put that as the answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:overScrollMode="never">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:fadingEdge="none"` at your xml file